# Pronunciation of "Jews" vs "juice"

Tags: pronunciation, homophones

Is there a different pronunciation for the word "Jews" and the word "juice"?

EDIT: I am referring specifically to the vowels in these words, apart from the ending consonant. It seems to me that the "w" letter in "Jews" makes the pronunciation more tense, but it may be only my impression

Comment: As I understand (and it's the way I speak), *Jews* ~ /dʒuːz/ and *juice* ~ /dʒuːs/.

Comment: What @DamkerngT. - is perfectly accurate. `"Jews"` is ended with a Z sound whereas `"juice"` ends with an S sound.

Comment: I really meant more on the "u/w" sound. I did not know about the "s" vs "z". I once mentioned in an ironic way that I ordered an "apple Jews" and the person did not catch the irony until she said "oh Juuuwws" (like the u was longer in Jews). In the dictionary, however, the "u" sound is the same

Comment: @Ralph People sometimes lengthen vowels/words for emphasis. It's not necessarily because she thought the u sound was longer in Jews (though it doesn't discount it either).

Comment: Yes, they're different. See also on ELU [Are “whores” and “horse” homophones?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342273)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both start with a J and the J retains the same pronunciation. English is sometimes reliable. The 'ce' and the 'ws' are slightly different, because they sound more like 'ss' and 'wez' respectively.

With that out the way, the vowels: they are the same. An 'E' followed by a 'W' (and maybe some other letters (and not in all cases)) sounds like 'oo'. The 'ui' in juice is also pronounced as a 'oo'.

That should clear it up.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question and the misunderstanding (for me the "w" is a vowel). From your question I infer that the pronunciation between the "u" and the "s"/"z" is a bit different since there is a bit of "w". Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. It's a very subtle 'w' though, so make sure you don't put much emphasis on it. The word is strictly one syllable. :)

Answer (score 9):

The vowel in *Jews* is longer than the vowel in *juice*, because there is a voiced consonant after it. Many dialects of English lengthen vowels before voiced consonants ([See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length#Allophonic_vowel_length).)

I don't believe it's the "w" that makes the difference. For me, the vowel sounds the same in *Jews* and *excuse* (verb), and in *juice* and *excuse* (noun).

In several dialects, the vowel actually changes quality before a voiced consonant; see [Canadian raising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_raising).

Comment: This is correct.  Just say the following pairs to yourself – plays/place, grows/gross, bruise/Bruce.  The first word in each pair definitely has a slightly longer vowel.